# query to find on which day (Monday to Sunday) an employee was hired?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to find out the day on which an employee was hired. in a normal SQL language will help

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
to_char(the_date_field,'d')
```

This will return a value of 1-7 representing the day of the week.

or

```
to_char(the_date_field,'Day')
```

to return the day name.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is a hire date in the database. You should know the proper names of the table and fields in the table. If the fields are in different tables, you will need to perform a "join" query with multiple tables.

select employee_name, hire_date from table_name
where employee_number = 99999999
for browse access;